# using iloc to query a pandas dataframe, why pylance is complaining slice is "slice" is incompatible with "int"?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, visual-studio-code, pylance

I am using iloc to slice my dataframe as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6]})
new_df = df.iloc[1:]
```

It is working fine but pylance in VsCode is complaining that:

```
Argument of type "slice" cannot be assigned to parameter "idx" of type "int | Tuple[IndexType | MaskType, IndexType | MaskType | int]" in function "__getitem__"
  Type "slice" cannot be assigned to type "int | Tuple[IndexType | MaskType, IndexType | MaskType | int]"
    "slice" is incompatible with "int"
    "slice" is incompatible with "Tuple[IndexType | MaskType, IndexType | MaskType | int]"
```

Any idea why and what does it mean?

Comment: Your exact code works for me (v1.3.4), which pandas version are you using?

Comment: Works fine for me too. Update your VSC

Comment: It means that `pylance` doesn't believe that `df.iloc` can be sliced, only directly indexed. [According to the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), however, `pylance` is wrong. It's important to understand that ultimately, what your IDE and plugins believe about the code doesn't matter - what matters is the result of your testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read it like this :
"you put brackets so i call get_item, and inside should be an index (idx), and this index should be of type : int | Tuple[IndexType | MaskType, IndexType | MaskType | int]  however, slice is compatible with none of it."

Have you tried replacing `:` with `,` ? it says he expect a Tuple of int, maybe that helps?

But you say it works? so it may be an issue with pylance, no?

**== Edit ==**

The answer is : `df.iloc[1:,:]`

Comment: Tried `df.iloc[1:,:]` and pylance no more showing warning